# How to get data from users in Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-studio-3.0

I'm new to Firebase and what I want to do is get the name of the users in my database, but without using the 'usuarios' childs. Hope I explained correctly.

[image: database schema]

This is what I'm trying:

```
 myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = postSnapshot.child("usuarios").child("luisito").child("nombre").getValue(String.class);


                Toast.makeText(UsuariosEnLineaActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }};
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }});
```

The code above gets the name but, I want the name of all users. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
myRef.child("Administrador").child("usuarios").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = postSnapshot.child("nombre").getValue(String.class);
               names.add(name);

                }};
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }});
```

Now `names` contains all the names.

Comment: int listSize = names.size();

                for (int i = 0; i<listSize; i++){
                    Log.i("Member name: ", names.get(i));
                }

Comment: FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

Comment: glad i could help you :)